# How to eliminate Free Pascal 'not recognized' compile error on TFileStream?

Tags: freepascal, tfilestream

I am using Free Pascal 2.6.4 32-bit on Windows 8.1. I want to use a TFileStream to copy a file.

```
program copy;

procedure CopyFile (strFilename : string);
var
   SourceF, DestF :  TFileStream;
begin
end;
begin
   writeln('starting ');

end.
```

The compiler is not recognizing the TFileStream:

```
fpc copy_small.pas
Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.4 [2014/03/06] for i386
Copyright (c) 1993-2014 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: Win32 for i386
Compiling copy_small.pas
copy_small.pas(5,33) Error: Identifier not found "TFileStream"
copy_small.pas(5,33) Error: Error in type definition
copy_small.pas(12) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling module, stopping
Fatal: Compilation aborted
Error: C:\FPC\2.6.4\bin\i386-Win32\ppc386.exe returned an error exitcode (normal if you did not specify a source file to be compiled)
```

The sample code I found on the web using TFileStream did not have a "uses" clause. Is there something that needs to be set on the command line or included in the program in order to use a TFileStream with Free Pascal?

Comment: @MitchWheat I think a better question is why do you care what programming languages other people use. Reminds me of iPhone users who have a tizzy when someone pulls out a Blackberry.

Comment: @MitchWheat It's good that we have you to tell us what the popular languages are so we don't have to google.

Comment: So, why are you using Pascal?

Comment: @MitchWheat Primarily nostalgia, as I am old enough to have dabbled with Turbo Pascal on DOS, but also because it is not in fashion, as I like things out of fashion or unpopular, and also because it can do something most modern languages cannot - make executables on the three main OS platforms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61615/discussion-between-scooter-and-mitch-wheat).

Comment: @Scooter `TFileStream` lives in the `Classes` unit, so the answer to your question is: use `Classes` unit in your program (in the `uses` section). @MitchWheat Quality of the product usually not depends on programming language but on programmer's skills.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks, that did the trick! You should put it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TFileStream` lives in the `Classes` unit, so your code should be

```
program copy;

// To use any 'non-system' functionality add necessary units here
uses
  Classes;

procedure CopyFile (strFilename : string);
var
   SourceF, DestF :  TFileStream;
begin
end;
begin
   writeln('starting ');

end.
```